# Не могу определить юзера при создании новой модели DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Также **сериализатор**:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Профиль юзера

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'user', 'name', 'surname', 
            'patronymic', 'kind', 'regions', 
            'phone', 'company', 'categories'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        return profile
```

**views:**

```py
class ProfileCreate(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # Создание профиля юзера

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        profile = serializer.save()
        return Response(ProfileSerializer(profile))
```

Как я понимаю, вся проблема в том когда проверяются данные в структуре

```py
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Выдаётся ошибка **"User - это обязательное поле"**

Видимо нужно не при создании профиля определять юзера, а при валидации данных передавать его.
Но вопрос, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Проблема решена**.
Следовало просто убрать из fields поле user, для того чтобы оно стало необязательным.
Благодаря методу create в сериализаторе юзер сохраняется.